# Google search console says 2 redirect errors out of 15 pages using hreflang

Tags: redirects, search, hreflang, rel-alternate

My website on Github Pages has 15 different pages for different languages and locales.  They all have the following in the head block.

```
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index.html" hreflang="x-default" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-de.html" hreflang="de" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-fr.html" hreflang="fr" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-es.html" hreflang="es" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-it.html" hreflang="it" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-pl.html" hreflang="pl" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-se.html" hreflang="se" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-ru.html" hreflang="ru" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-ua.html" hreflang="uk" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-in.html" hreflang="in" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-cn.html" hreflang="zh" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-jp.html" hreflang="ja" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-ca.html" hreflang="en-ca" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-fr-ca.html" hreflang="fr-ca" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-au.html" hreflang="en-au" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-gb.html" hreflang="en-gb" />
```

Google Search Console is complaining about redirect errors for two of those pages: index-de.html and index-fr.html.  I can't figure out what's wrong.

Also, should I have an alternate link for "en" or is the "x-default" good enough?

**Update:**

OK, I set it up as recommended, but it still fails to index:

main page:  `https://359north.com/index.html`

```
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://359north.com" />

    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="https://359north.com/au" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-CA" href="https://359north.com/ca" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="https://359north.com/gb" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://359north.com" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-CA" href="https://359north.com/fr-ca" />

    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://359north.com/de" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://359north.com/fr" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://359north.com/es" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="https://359north.com/it" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pl" href="https://359north.com/pl" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="sv" href="https://359north.com/se" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" href="https://359north.com/ru" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="uk" href="https://359north.com/ua" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="hi" href="https://359north.com/in" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh" href="https://359north.com/cn" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="https://359north.com/jp" />

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://359north.com">
```

secondary page:  `https://359north.com/gb/index.html`

```
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://359north.com" />

    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="https://359north.com/au" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-CA" href="https://359north.com/ca" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="https://359north.com/gb" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://359north.com" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-CA" href="https://359north.com/fr-ca" />

    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://359north.com/de" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://359north.com/fr" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://359north.com/es" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="https://359north.com/it" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pl" href="https://359north.com/pl" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="sv" href="https://359north.com/se" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" href="https://359north.com/ru" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="uk" href="https://359north.com/ua" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="hi" href="https://359north.com/in" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh" href="https://359north.com/cn" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="https://359north.com/jp" />

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://359north.com/gb">
```

Answer (score 3):

First,

```html
<link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/index-fr.html" hreflang="fr" />
```

This is not a conventional way to specify a multi-regional/multilingual version of a page. Google's guidelines cite the use a subdomain or sub directory for the lang code...or have ccTLDs.

I suppose you still have unique pages for each country/language but I'd prefer to see it implemented in a conventional way.

[image]

So you'd have either:

```
https://en.example.com/index.html
https://fr.example.com/index.html
etc...
```

or

```
https://example.com/en/index.html
https://example.com/fr/index.html
etc...
```

Also what about `https://359north.com`? This is reachable, and likely the expected homepage, yet for your home button you link to /index.html. So you need to make a decision there. I would drop the `index.html` across the board. Here is an example of a correct (albeit incomplete) implementation assuming you're based in the US:

```html
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://359north.com" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="https://359north.com/en-gb" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://359north.com/de" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://359north.com/fr" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://359north.com" />
```

Ardacar's theory that your redirect problem might have to do with no canonicals set is plausible. However, to me it seems like a Search Console false positive bug because you're only seeing this for two random pages. Make sure that you set up the canonicals correctly, as there is a very common wrong way to do this that I see all the time.

```html
<!--British page-->

<link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/en-gb" hreflang="en-GB" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com" hreflang="en-US"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://359north.com"/>
```

The above tells search engines that even if a British user searches for this page, we’d like the US page to show up in search results.

So the correct way to do this would be:

```html
<!--USA Page-->

<link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/en-GB" hreflang="en-GB" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com" hreflang="en-US" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://359north.com"/>
```

```html
<!--On British Page-->

<link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/en-gb" hreflang="en-GB" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://359north.com/" hreflang="en-US" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://359north.com/en-gb"/>
```